# the uri specification in xml namespaces

Tags: xml

I was going through an example on http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

There is an example using the following xml:

```
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">


<f:table>
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

</root>
```

However when i tried to access the URL "http://www.w3schools.com/furniture", it showed me 404. So, what is the significance of using the URI ? Is the xml meant to access the internet while being used ? Or is it for the reference of the person using the xml. And instead of using such URI name, isn't it easy to give just a small id say "furniture".  Also, let's say i use URI, then as the owner of the xml, what information I am supposed to provide at that URI ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> So, what is the significance of using the URI ?

It uniquely identifies the namespace.

> Is the xml meant to access the internet while being used ?

No

> Or is it for the reference of the person using the xml.

No

> And instead of using such URI name, isn't it easy to give just a small id say "furniture".

That would make it much more likely that multiple people will independently create a namespace called "furniture" that is incompatible with all the others.

You would use `xmlns:furniture="http://example.com/..."` to give it a short name for use in the document.

> Also, let's say i use URI, then as the owner of the xml, what information I am supposed to provide at that URI ?

It is customary to provide some documentation. Possibly in the form of a schema.